# ListView OnClickListener not working within TabActivity

Tags: android, listview, onclick, expandablelistview, tabactivity

I have a ListView and an ExpandableListView inside of a TabActivity.  I have overridden the setOnItemClickListener for the ListView.  I have 2 tabs and one uses the ListView and the other uses the ExpandableListView.  For some reason I cannot click on any of the items in the first ListView.  If I change tabs to the ExpandableListView and then go back to the first tab it will then allow me to click on the items as usual.  Any ideas on why this is happening.  Is there some kind of weird focus thing going on?

I have this as part of my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
                    onListItemClick(pos, id);
                    // return false;
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue right now.  I'll post a solution if I find one.

Not the solution I'm looking for... but here is what worked in the interim.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //lv is a reference to my ListView.
    lv.setSelection(position);

    return convertView;
}
```

Let me note that this is not an ideal solution, it's just something that seems to work consistently on Android versions > 1.5.  (That is what I tested with).

An additional note here, you are using the onItemClickListener as well and this typically only responds to the use of the trackball or arrow keys on the emulator.  That might your situation for not handling the onClick event.  I use a typical

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. Some ListViews dispatched by a TabActivity.
I couldn't set a proper `OnItemClickListener`, so I attached an `OnClickListener` "manually" in the Adapter to the `convertView`.
It just attaches an OnClickListener at each cell.

Just like this :

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // What you want to do with this "item click"
        // make an Intent to start something else or whatever
    }
});
```

Of course you do this in the Adapter method (e.g. before returning the convertView) :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

That worked in my case, so I hope it helps you out.

Good luck

Comment: Oh and by the way if you need the position of your item in the list, just set it as a Tag for your convertView, that way you'll get it back in the onClick method.